# Prolog: DCGS - Converting numbers to English

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm practicing using DCGs in Prolog.  I take an integer like 123, 'explode' it into a list i.e. [1,2,3] and then I want to use DCG rules to get the output one-two-three.  So far I can convert a list of one integer e.g. [1] into one but I don't know what to do when it comes to a list.  I want to use DCGs as much as possible really as this is what I am practicing.  Here's my current code:

```
tests( 1, [1] ).
tests( 2, [67] ).
tests( 3, [183] ).
tests( 4, [999] ).  

numToEng( N, Res ) :-
    tests( N, W ),
    print( 'test: ' ),print( W ),nl,
    explode( W, Exploded ),
    print( 'exploded: ' ),print( Exploded ),nl,
    phrase( num(Res), Exploded ).

explode( N, Explosion ) :-
    explode( N, [], Explosion ).
explode( 0, Explosion, Explosion ) :- !.    
explode( N, Inter, Explosion ) :- 
    Test is N mod 10, 
    NewN0 is  N - Test,
    NewN1 is NewN0//10, 
    explode( NewN1, [Test|Inter], Explosion ).

num( X ) --> digit( X ).    

digit(zero) --> [0].
digit(one) --> [1].
digit(two) --> [2].
digit(three) --> [3].
digit(four) --> [4].
digit(five) --> [5].
digit(six) --> [6].
digit(seven) --> [7].
digit(eight) --> [8].
digit(nine) --> [9].
```

A possible solution WITHOUT using DCGs is what I've written before but I'm wondering how to write it using DCGs.

```
% test cases, called by numToEng/2
tests( 1, [1] ).
tests( 2, [67] ).
tests( 3, [183] ).
tests( 4, [999] ).

% dictionary
digit(0,zero).
digit(1,one).
digit(2,two).
digit(3,three).
digit(4,four).
digit(5,five).
digit(6,six).
digit(7,seven).
digit(8,eight).
digit(9,nine).

% take an integer e.g. 123 and explode it
% into a list i.e. [1,2,3]
explode( N, Explosion ) :-
    explode( N, [], Explosion ).
explode( 0, Explosion, Explosion ) :- !.    
explode( N, Inter, Explosion ) :- 
    Test is N mod 10, 
    NewN0 is  N - Test,
    NewN1 is NewN0//10, 
    explode( NewN1, [Test|Inter], Explosion ).

% take a number in digits and convert it
% into english e.g. [1,2,3] would be
% [one,two,three]   
numToEng( N, Res ) :-
    tests( N, Test ),
    explode( Test, Exploded ),
    numToEng( N, Exploded, [], Res ).
numToEng( _, [], Rev, Res ) :-
    reverse( Rev, Res ).
numToEng( N, [H|T], Inter, Res ) :-
    digit( H, Word ),
    numToEng( N, T, [Word|Inter], Res ).
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry, basically I want to convert an integer into a list of English words so 123 becomes [one, two, three].  I want to be able to do this using DCG grammar rules.  I have given a non-DCG example so you can see what I want.  I think this can be solved using DCG rules?  Is that enough info?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
digits([]) --> [].
digits([D|Ds]) --> digit(D), digits(Ds).
```

Example:

```
?- explode(123,X), digits(Digits,X,[]).
X = [1, 2, 3],
Digits = [one, two, three]
```